# Specialization with Constraints

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm having problems getting GHC to specialize a function with a class constraint. I have a minimal example of my problem here: [Foo.hs](http://lpaste.net/98464) and  [Main.hs](http://lpaste.net/98342). The two files compile (GHC 7.6.2, `ghc -O3 Main`) and run.

**NOTE:**
`Foo.hs` is really stripped down. If you want to see why the constraint is needed, you can see a little more code [here](http://lpaste.net/98840). If I put the code in a single file or make many other minor changes, GHC simply inlines the call to `plusFastCyc`. This will not happen in the real code because `plusFastCyc` is too large for GHC to inline, even when marked `INLINE`. The point is to *specialize* the call to `plusFastCyc`, not inline it. `plusFastCyc` is called in many places in the real code, so duplicating such a large function would not be desirable even if I could force GHC to do it.

The code of interest is the `plusFastCyc` in `Foo.hs`, reproduced here:

```
{-# INLINEABLE plusFastCyc #-}
{-# SPECIALIZE plusFastCyc :: 
         forall m . (Factored m Int) => 
              (FastCyc (VT U.Vector m) Int) -> 
                   (FastCyc (VT U.Vector m) Int) -> 
                        (FastCyc (VT U.Vector m) Int) #-}

-- Although the next specialization makes `fcTest` fast,
-- it isn't useful to me in my real program because the phantom type M is reified
-- {-# SPECIALIZE plusFastCyc :: 
--          FastCyc (VT U.Vector M) Int -> 
--               FastCyc (VT U.Vector M) Int -> 
--                    FastCyc (VT U.Vector M) Int #-}

plusFastCyc :: (Num (t r)) => (FastCyc t r) -> (FastCyc t r) -> (FastCyc t r)
plusFastCyc (PowBasis v1) (PowBasis v2) = PowBasis $ v1 + v2
```

The `Main.hs` file has two drivers: `vtTest`, which runs in ~3 seconds, and `fcTest`, which runs in ~83 seconds when compiled with -O3 using the `forall`'d specialization.

The [core shows](http://lpaste.net/98593) that for the `vtTest` test, the addition code is being specialized to `Unboxed` vectors over `Int`s, etc, while generic vector code is used for `fcTest`.
On line 10, you can see that GHC does write a specialized version of `plusFastCyc`, compared to the generic version on line 167.
The rule for the specialization is on line 225. I believe this rule should fire on line 270. (`main6` calls `iterate main8 y`, so `main8` is where `plusFastCyc` should be specialized.)

My goal is to make `fcTest` as fast as `vtTest` by specializing `plusFastCyc`. I've found two ways to do this:

1. Explicity call `inline` from `GHC.Exts` in `fcTest`.
2. Remove the `Factored m Int` constraint on `plusFastCyc`.

Option 1 is unsatisfactory because in the actual code base `plusFastCyc` is a frequently used operation and a *very* large function, so it should not be inlined at every use. Rather, GHC should call a specialized version of `plusFastCyc`. Option 2 is not really an option because I need the constraint in the real code.

I've tried a variety of options using (and not using) `INLINE`, `INLINABLE`, and `SPECIALIZE`, but nothing seems to work. (**EDIT**: I may have stripped out too much of `plusFastCyc` to make my example small, so `INLINE` might cause the function to be inlined. This doesn't happen in my real code because `plusFastCyc` is so large.) In this particular example, I'm not getting any [`match_co: needs more cases`](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/2B0uXzyXUnvOzzIApVfp) or [`RULE: LHS too complicated to desugar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792388/haskell-ghc-specialize-causes-rule-left-hand-side-too-complicated-to) (and [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5821)) warnings, though I was getting many `match_co` warnings before minimizing the example. Presumably, the "problem" is the `Factored m Int` constraint in the rule; if I make changes to that constraint, `fcTest` runs as fast as `vtTest`.

Am I doing something GHC just doesn't like? Why won't GHC specialize the `plusFastCyc`, and how can I make it?

**UPDATE**

The problem persists in GHC 7.8.2, so this question is still relevant.

Comment: I just tried specializing for a *specific* `m`, namely `M`. This got the job done, but I can't specialize for specific phantom types in the real program as they are reified.

Comment: I also submitted a GHC bug report https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8668 but the problem is still open. The bug report process helped me clean up the question a bit, so hopefully it will be easier to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @monojohnny Sorry to hear that, I believe you can flag it as such. I think I'm asking GHC to do something fairly reasonable, and it won't do it. I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong, or if this is an idiosyncrasy with the compiler that might have a workaround. I've seen workarounds for specialization and rules in some specific library on hackage that escapes me at the moment, so I'm hoping someone in the community with more GHC experience than myself might know how to achieve specialization.

Comment: I apologize for the tone of my comment - it's not my best contribution to this site - there is really nothing wrong with your post (It's my lack of understanding that was the source of my annoyance I guess !)

Comment: @monojohnny Apology accepted, but it's too bad that downvote is locked in now ;-)

Comment: ah yes, sorry about that - I believe you can edit the post and this will allow me to neutralize the down-vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GHC also gives an option to `SPECIALIZE` a type-class instance declaration. I tried this with the (expanded) code of `Foo.hs`, by putting the following:

```
instance (Num r, V.Vector v r, Factored m r) => Num (VT v m r) where 
    {-# SPECIALIZE instance ( Factored m Int => Num (VT U.Vector m Int)) #-}
    VT x + VT y = VT $ V.zipWith (+) x y
```

This change, though, did not achieve the desired speedup. What did achieve that performance improvement was *manually* adding a specialized instance for the type `VT U.Vector m Int` with the same function definitions, as follows:

```
instance (Factored m Int) => Num (VT U.Vector m Int) where 
    VT x + VT y = VT $ V.zipWith (+) x y
```

This requires adding `OverlappingInstances` and `FlexibleInstances` in  `LANGUAGE`.

Interestingly, in the example program, the speedup obtained with the overlapping instance remains even if you remove every `SPECIALIZE` and `INLINABLE` pragma.

Comment: Definitely not optimal, but it's the first solution that actually accomplishes the goal, so I guess I'll take it for now...