# Specializing related polymorphic functions without inlining

Tags: performance, haskell, inline, ghc

Here's a minimal example reproducing a real problem I'm working on:

One library module:

```
module Lib where

class H h where
  hash :: (S s)=> s -> h -> s

class S s where
  mix :: s -> Int -> s

instance (H x, H y)=> H (x,y) where
  hash s = \(x,y) ->
    s `hash` x `hash` y
      -- make this look "big":
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y
      `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y `hash` x `hash` y

instance H Int where
  hash s = \n -> s `mix` n
```

Another, possibly defined by a user:

```
module S where

import Lib

newtype Foo = Foo Int
    deriving Show

instance S Foo where
  mix (Foo x) y = Foo (x+y)
```

And our `Main`:

```
module Main where

import Lib
import S

import Criterion.Main

main = defaultMain [
    bench "foo" $ whnf (hash (Foo 1)) (2::Int,3::Int)
  ]
```

Compiling with ghc 8.0.1 with `ghc --make -Wall -O2 -rtsopts -ddump-to-file -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-module-prefixes -dsuppress-uniques -ddump-core-stats -ddump-inlinings -fforce-recomp Main.hs`.

The benchmark above runs in **4 μs**. If however we put `INLINE` pragmas on the two `hash` declarations in `Lib` we see the expected specializations we want and get a runtime of **66 ns**.

But I don't really want to inline everything (in the user's real `Main` she might be calling `hash` many many times on the same type), I just want the function specialized for every combination of `H` and `S` instance in the user's code.

Changing `INLINE` pragmas to `INLINABLE` caused a regression to the old behavior (expected I think, since GHC's inlining heuristics are still at play). I then tried adding

```
{-# SPECIALIZE hash :: H a=> Foo -> a -> Foo #-}
```

to both `Main` and `S` modules but this generates

```
Ignoring useless SPECIALISE pragma for class method selector ‘hash’
```

...warnings and the same bad code.

Some constraints:

- It would be acceptable though not ideal to require every `S` instance declaration to include a finite number of pragmas (possibly related to `H`)
- likewise for `H`
- it's not acceptable to require users to do a `SPECIALIZE` for every combination of `S` and `H`.

Is it possible to do this without INLINE?

This is probably the same as [Specialization with Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071706/specialization-with-constraints) and related trac ticket https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8668, but I thought I would ask again and possibly post this as a simpler example to the GHC Trac.

---

**EDIT**: went ahead and opened a ghc ticket: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13376

Comment: What if in the instance you define `hash s n = myHash s n` (inlined) and then outside you declare a specialized `myHash` for your case? (Just a wild guess)

Comment: @chi if I follow you, one issue there is I'm not able to actually specialize manually on every combination of `H` and `S` since their defined by different users. But I played around with various things like what you suggested and got various combinations of no effect and ghc panics (which look to have probably been fixed in head). Thanks though, I'll definitely post if I find a good workaround